# Uso di "notare" + infinito

Tags: word-usage, verbs

In un esercizio di italiano ho trovato la frase seguente:

> L'uomo **è stato notato aggirarsi** in atteggiamento sospetto tra i reparti della libreria di via Nazionale.

La struttura "notare" + infinito ha attirato la mia attenzione perché a me risulta del tutto nuova, soprattutto quando è nella forma passiva, come in questo esempio. Potreste farmi alcuni esempi per poter capire come usare questo costrutto?

Comment: *Notare*, *vedere*, *sentire*: tutti i verbi di percezione accettano questa costruzione.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'infinito pronominale "aggirarsi" in questo caso esprime in forma implicita una subordinata completiva con valore soggettivo, che in forma esplicita potrebbe essere resa con "che si aggirava" o "mentre si aggirava".

L'infinito con i verbi di percezione va considerato alla stregua della cosiddetta infinitiva latina, una proposizione oggetiva o soggettiva con il verbo all'infinito.

Ad esempio:

Lat. *Eum vident sedere ad latus praetoris* (It. impl. "vedono egli sedere al lato del pretore"; It. espl.: "vedono che egli siede al lato del pretore").

In G. Rohlfs, *[Grammatica storica della lingua italiana e dei suoi dialetti](https://archive.org/stream/GrammaticaStoricaDellaLinguaItaliana3/Grammatica%20storica%20della%20lingua%20italiana%203#page/n65/mode/1up)*, III, Torino 1969, il § 706 (pp. 87-89) viene trattato proprio l'"**accusativo con l'infinito**", e sono citati alcuni esempi di come tale costrutto possa essere considerato una imitazione del latino, nato in epoca umanistica ma progressivamente caduto in disuso:

- sapere adunque dovete in Lombardia essere un famosissimo monistero (Boccaccio, *Decam.* 9,2)
- credevano essere quella un'unzione velenosa (Manzoni, *Prom.* 31)

Per citare i verbi menzionati nel commento di egreg, si possono addurre i seguenti esempi:

- Verbo principale in forma attiva:

Impl. "Noto aumentare il livello di pericolo"
Espl. "Noto che aumenta il livello di pericolo"

Impl. "Vedo venir meno il coraggio nei giovani"
Espl. "Vedo che il coraggio nei giovani viene meno"

Impl. "Sento crescere il mio amore per te" 
Espl. "sento che il mio amore per te cresce"

- Verbo principale in forma passiva:

Impl. "è stato visto rubare e scappare"
Espl. "è stato visto che rubava e scappava"

Altri esempi e approfondimenti in G. Skytte, *[La sintassi dell'infinito in italiano moderno](https://books.google.it/books?id=FoK0D9fYn3AC&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=ulrich%20schwendener%20Der%20Accusativus%20Infinitivo%20im%20Italienischen&source=bl&ots=FUGkUY7itw&sig=d-rtnsaHlcAxJ2ZOrPAdiMRI4Ps&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwippNGEycnRAhVmLcAKHR11BHMQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=ulrich%20schwendener%20Der%20Accusativus%20Infinitivo%20im%20Italienischen&f=false)*, Copenhagen 1983, pp. 299-301; U. Schwendener, *[Der Accusativus cum Infinitivo im Italienischen](https://archive.org/details/deraccusativuscu00schwuoft)*, Säckingen am Rhein 1923.

Comment: Cosa c'entra il latino qui? Non mi sembra che aiuti a chiarire la spiegazione.

Comment: Quale aspetto della risposta non ti convince? Ho ritenuto che per spiegare meglio l'uso del costrutto fosse appropriato partire da una prospettiva diacronica

Comment: Non mi convince che ci sia bisogno di passare dal latino per spiegare una costruzione della grammatica italiana. C'è anche gente che studia l'italiano senza sapere il latino (e, secondo me, sono la maggioranza).

Comment: Certamente una costruzione della grammatica italiana puà essere spiegata a livello pratico e descrittivo ("cos'è?"), ma ciò è impossibile se si vuole comprenderne appieno le dinamiche strutturali ("perché è?") e le particolarità sintattiche. Certo dipende dal livello su cui ci si vuole soffermare. Ma credo che in molti casi la conoscenza del latino aiuterebbe anche sul piano descrittivo: l'Italiano deriva dal Latino. In certi casi è come scindere la descrizione geografica dei confini attuali di uno stato con la spiegazione storica del perché essi abbiano una determinata conformazione.

Comment: @Charo ho aggiunto alcuni link dove potrai eventualmente trovare altri esempi